# ASP.NET MVC 3: ViewModel that deals with a list of lists

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I'm trying to put together a ViewModel that will have a list of users and each user will have a list of locations. 
The User table and Location table are joined together through another table that holds each respective ID and some other information. This table is essentially a many to many join table.
I've tried a few different viewModel approaches and they we're severely lacking... What would be the best approach for displaying this type of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the issue is that you want to be able to access the collection by either User or Location.  One approach could be to use `ILookup<>` classes.  You'd start with the many-to-many collection and produce the lookups like this:

```
var lookupByUser = userLocations.ToLookup(ul => ul.User);
var lookupByLocation = userLocations.ToLookup(ul => ul.Location);
```

**Update:**

Per your description, it seems like you don't really need to have a full many-to-many relationship in your ViewModel.  Rather, your ViewModel could have a structure like this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    // User-related stuff

    public IEnumerable<LocationViewModel> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

If you wanted to avoid redundant `LocationViewModel` objects, you could pre-build a mapping between your Model and ViewModel objects:

```
var locationViewModels = myLocations.ToDictionary(
    loc => loc, loc => CreateLocationViewModel(loc));
```

And then reuse these objects when populating your page's ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for the start, however I'm still new to MVC, so could you go a little more in depth.

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to display?  The ViewModel should be tailored to what the View needs to render.

Comment: The View is going to display all the Users and then under each user, all the locations for that particular user will be listed out. Does that help?